How to get query parameter values in laravel + Intertia Vue?
How to access to the query parameters in laravel + inertia vue js.?
<script>
  export default {
  computed: {
   reference() {
    return this.$page.props.query.reference || 'No reference provided';
   }
  }
 };
</script>


We can access using this way. its working for me.
<script>
 let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
 console.log(params.get('YourParam))
</script>


You could do something like this:
function $route() {
    const query = {};

    const url = new URL(this.$page.url, window.location.origin);

    for (const [key, value] of url.searchParams.entries()) {
        query[key] = value;
    }

    return {
        origin: window.location.origin,
        path: url.pathname,
        fullUrl: url,
        query,
    };
  }
}

This can then be injected via mixins or better still you can make it a composable.
